# Error Building Scilab Toolbox: Setting Environment Variables

Tags: java, debugging, environment-variables, scilab, chroot

I'm encountering an error while developing a Java-based software using Scilab. Below, I've outlined the details of the problem:

Startup Execution:
When attempting to execute the file /Users/vimalchawda/Desktop/spacecraft-gnc-tbx/builder.sce, the startup process loads the initial environment.

Building Process:
During the execution, the following steps are taken in the building process:

Macros are being built, resulting in the creation of [spacecraft_gnc_tbxlib] (Macros).
Files related to the Kalman Filter (Kalman_Filter_IF.sci, Kalman_Filter_SIM.sci, Kalman_Filter_Utils.sci) are processed.
Blocks are being built.
Help documents are being generated, including the master document located at /Users/vimalchawda/Desktop/spacecraft-gnc-tbx/help/en_US.
The manual file [javaHelp] is being built in the specified directory.
Error Message:
An error occurs during the building process at line 693 of the xmltoformat function, which is called from xmltojar and subsequently from tbx_build_help. The error trace indicates that the issue originates from a function call in the file builder_help.sce.

Suggested Solution:
The error message suggests that setting two environment variables (SCI_DISABLE_TK=1 and SCI_JAVA_ENABLE_HEADLESS=1) might resolve the issue, especially if Scilab is started in a chroot environment.

Request for Assistance:
Given the error message and the suggested solution involving environment variables, I seek guidance on how to properly set these environment variables in my Scilab development environment. Any insights or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

**Part 1 code is this for builder.sce file**

{.

```
    mode(-1);
    lines(0);

    function main_builder()

        TOOLBOX_NAME  = "spacecraft_gnc_tbx";
        TOOLBOX_TITLE = "Spacecraft GNC Toolbox";
        toolbox_dir   = get_absolute_file_path("builder.sce");

        // Check Scilab's version
        // 
 

        // check minimal version (xcosPal required)
        if ~isdef("xcosPal") then
            // and xcos features required
            error(gettext("Scilab 5.3.2 or more is required."));
        end

        // Check modules_manager module availability


        if ~isdef("tbx_build_loader") then
            error(msprintf(gettext("%s module not installed."), 
        "modules_manager"));
        end


        if ~isdir(toolbox_dir+filesep()+"images"+filesep()+"h5")
            [status, msg] = 
        mkdir(toolbox_dir+filesep()+"images"+filesep()+"h5");
            if and(status <> [1 2])
                error(msg);
            end
        end

        // Action
        // 

        tbx_builder_macros(toolbox_dir);
        tbx_builder_help(toolbox_dir);
        tbx_build_loader(TOOLBOX_NAME, toolbox_dir);
        tbx_build_cleaner(TOOLBOX_NAME, toolbox_dir);
    endfunction

    if with_module("xcos") then
        main_builder();
        clear main_builder; // remove main_builder on stack
    end    
    ´´´

.}


 **2-Error part is** 

    Startup execution:
  loading initial environment

--> exec('/Users/vimalchawda/Desktop/spacecraft-gnc-tbx/builder.sce',-1)
Building macros...
-- Creation of [spacecraft_gnc_tbxlib] (Macros) --
genlib: Processing file: Kalman_Filter_IF.sci
genlib: Processing file: Kalman_Filter_SIM.sci
genlib: Processing file: Kalman_Filter_Utils.sci
Building blocks...
Building help...

Building the master document:
    /Users/vimalchawda/Desktop/spacecraft-gnc-tbx/help/en_US

Building the manual file [javaHelp] in /Users/vimalchawda/Desktop/spacecraft-gnc-tbx/help/en_US.
at line   693 of function xmltoformat           ( /Applications/scilab-2024.0.0.app/Contents/share/scilab/modules/helptools/macros/xmltoformat.sci line 710 )
at line    17 of function xmltojar              ( /Applications/scilab-2024.0.0.app/Contents/share/scilab/modules/helptools/macros/xmltojar.sci line 29 )
at line    51 of function tbx_build_help        ( /Applications/scilab-2024.0.0.app/Contents/share/scilab/modules/modules_manager/macros/tbx_build_help.sci line 67 )
at line     4 of executed file /Users/vimalchawda/Desktop/spacecraft-gnc-tbx/help/en_US/build_help.sce
at line    13 of function tbx_builder           ( /Applications/scilab-2024.0.0.app/Contents/share/scilab/modules/modules_manager/macros/tbx_builder.sci line 26 )
at line    49 of function tbx_builder_help_lang ( /Applications/scilab-2024.0.0.app/Contents/share/scilab/modules/modules_manager/macros/tbx_builder_help_lang.sci line 64 )
at line     4 of executed file /Users/vimalchawda/Desktop/spacecraft-gnc-tbx/help/builder_help.sce
at line    71 of function tbx_builder_help      ( /Applications/scilab-2024.0.0.app/Contents/share/scilab/modules/modules_manager/macros/tbx_builder_help.sci line 87 )
at line    35 of function main_builder          ( /Users/vimalchawda/Desktop/spacecraft-gnc-tbx/builder.sce line 45 )
at line    51 of executed file /Users/vimalchawda/Desktop/spacecraft-gnc-tbx/builder.sce

If Scilab is started in a chroot, you might want to try to set the two environment variables: SCI_DISABLE_TK=1 SCI_JAVA_ENABLE_HEADLESS=1

**3- QUESTION : How can I set environment ?**

I am just student and I dont how to deal with such error. Is anyone have any knowledge about it? Thank you

Debugging the development of java problem while running the software. **I can provide you all file or code if any expert is available**

Sorry if I made mistake here by posting this questions.
```

Comment: Mistakes can be rectified by [edit]ing your question. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You should provide the relevant code and debugging information in the question. That is how Stackoverflow should be used. This is not a forum to discuss or to engage in meetings. Reviewing the following links might help you to improve the question: [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Write a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also [The Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) may be able to help with any other questions about using correctly this site.